# Rails 4.2.1: `rspec` results in a blinking cursor as if app is initializing, nothing ever happens (spring??)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, rspec

I've been working on a new app for a few days, writing tests as I go. Until last night there hadn't been any problems. Now all of a sudden when I run `rspec` the cursor just moves to the next line as it normally does while waiting for the app to initialize, except the specs never actually run. It seems to be permanently frozen/hanging and I have to use `ctrl + c` to stop the process.

Normally I would attribute this to the `spring` gem freaking out. I do have this in the Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-commands-rspec"
  gem "web-console"
end
```

However, I used `spring stop` and the problem continues. I also used `ps aux | grep spring` to make sure all spring processes were stopped and I still can't run my tests. In my desperation I went so far as to take `spring` and `spring-commands-rspec` our of the `Gemfile`, run `bundle`, and try again, but the process *still* just hangs.

Not sure if this is related, but now when I run `ps aux | grep spring` I still get this output:

```
me       72973   0.0  0.0  2432772    672 s000  S+    1:40PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn spring
```

It mentions `spring` at the very end but when I use `kill -9 72973` I get the error message `kill: kill 72973 failed: no such process`.

If I `cd` into another app directly, `rspec` works fine.

Anyone have any idea what might be going on? What could I try as a next debug step?

Comment: Please copy-paste your output.

Comment: There is no output. When I type `rspec` and press `enter` the cursor moves to the next line and just sits there.

Comment: try running just a single spec (eg `rspec spec/models/widgets_spec.rb`) ? or running via rake? `rake spec` ? (just to see if there's any difference)?